# Why i am getting 400 error if i used flask_session in my application?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-session

Recently i started to use flask_session extension in my application, also i am using **flask_wtf.csrf** extension token for security purposes.

Now , before flask_session the application worked perfectly , but when i installed flask_session and configured it parameters in my **config.py**, if i tried to login or to register the application gives me `400 Bad Request The CSRF session token is missing.`, in fact, i am including the csrf_token in all my requests including also ajax requests .

The session storing type is `sqlalchemy`:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'booking'
SESSION_TYPE = 'sqlalchemy'
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(seconds=120)
SESSION_SQLALCHEMY_TABLE = 'sessions'
SESSION_KEY_PREFIX = 'booking'
```

I forgot to mention, i noticed if i changed the type to 'filesystem' the error not showing up .

Here is the [flask_session documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) for more information.

**Login template**:

```
<form class="login_form" role="form" action="{{url_for('client.login')}}" method="post">
    {{ login_form.hidden_tag() }}

    {% if login_form.telephone.errors %}
        {% for e in login_form.telephone.errors %}
            <p class="text-error">{{e}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {{login_form.telephone(class="_bit mat_input", id="form-phone-number", placeholder="You login")}}

    {% if login_form.password.errors %}
        {% for e in login_form.password.errors %}
            <p class="text-error">{{e}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {{login_form.password(class="_bit mat_input",  id="form-password", placeholder="Your password")}}

    <a href="" class="login_button">
        <button type="submit" class="mat_button _bib">Login</button>
    </a>

    <div class="_dis_b rfb">
        <div class="remember_row">
            <label for="remember" class="remember">remember me</label>
            {{login_form.remember_me(id="remember", class="check")}}
        </div>
        <div class="forgot_row">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="forgot">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Client **views.py** :

```
@client_route.route('/client/cat-<dir_code>/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form_login = ClientLogin()
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.args.get('next'):
        session['next'] = request.args.get('next')

    if form_login.validate_on_submit():
        user = Client.query.filter_by(
            tele = form_login.telephone.data
        ).first()

        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form_login.password.data):
                session['client_logged_in'] = user.name
                session['client_family'] = user.family
                session['client_image'] = user.image
                session['client_phone'] = user.tele
                if 'next' in session:
                    next = session.get('next')
                    session.pop('next')
                    return redirect(next+'?current_user='+session.get('client_logged_in')+'+'+session.get('client_family'))
                else:
                    return redirect(url_for('client.lenta', dir_code=g.current_directory)+'?current_user='+session.get('client_logged_in')+'+'+session.get('client_family'))
            else:
                flash('Invalid credentials.', 'danger')
                return redirect(url_for('client.login', dir_code=g.current_directory))
        else:
            flash('Invalid credentials.', 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('client.login', dir_code=g.current_directory))
    return render_template('client/login.html', user=user, form_login=form_login)
```

Comment: Show your template file with *form* field

Comment: @Nabin, you can see it above , i updated the question !

Comment: Any suggestions guys , why i can't use **sqlalchemy** type with csrf token protection ?. With filesystem the application works fine, but i want to store them inside database !!

Comment: Post your python code section as well

Comment: @Nabin, added !

Comment: Have you enabled the `csrf ` in your app with `csrf = CsrfProtect(app)` . You  need to explicitly mention it.

Comment: @0decimal0, of course enabled !

Comment: As i said the application with `sqlalchemy` type not working , but with `filesystem` it work !

Comment: nobody knows whats wrong with that ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't set `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` at all and then go on from there and try alternatives.
Check whether you have set the configuration setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`. If you're working in localhost or through an unsecure line and you have set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True` then no session cookie will be sent and as such no forms, csrf protection and various other operations will work. Instead use `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False` under these circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old post, but for anyone with the same problem add below line to your settings.cfg file, 
It worked for me :

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "your_server_address"
```